# Delayed::Job - mutating job during perform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a background job that is unfortunately not transactionally safe. Currently this job is just scrapped if it fails leaving it half-completed.

I would like to introduce some state to the job and serialize that state during the perform method, so if the job fails and is retried, it can know to skip the already completed steps.

I know the job class is serialized when calling `Delayed::Job.enqueue`, but can it be reserialized during execution of the `perform` method?

Comment: You may want to consider breaking your job into smaller jobs and enqueue the next in the chain when one step completes. Without seeing any of your code, it's hard to prescribe exactly what you need though.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is to use a rescue block in which you will en-queue a new job of the same kind but with different object for serialization.